# Making responses that was appended into a Google form editable to an individual

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have historic data from an old directory that I successfully appended to  a new form using a script. However, I want the members of the directory to be able to edit, review and upload additional  data to their own record  without creating duplicate records. I know forms can be editable after an individual submits it and obtain a link. But is it possible for an individual to edit their record if it was appended into the form?

I'm a beginner in script, but I have experience coding and manipulating data in other software.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. You could use [getEditResponseUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#geteditresponseurl) to get a link to edit the response. Only you should decide where to you will record those links and how you will make the corresponding link available to those who should edit the response.